# How to test this boolean method in Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, boolean

Please need to test this method *paramsRequired* but not as it can reproduce the behavior for testing. How to know if when passing the null parameters the method will skip the *if*?

My class service

```
public class TestStack {
private GeoClassService service;

    public Address getAddress(String city,String neighborhood, boolean listOut) {
        List<GeoLocation> listLocation = new ArrayList<>();
        FutureTask<List<GeoLocation>> returnLoc = null;
    
        Address location = new Address();
        boolean paramsRequired = city!=null || neighborhood!=null;
        if (listOut && paramsRequired) {
            returnLoc = new FutureTask<>(() -> 
                    service.getAdrres(city,neighborhood, listOut));
            execute.executor(returnLoc);
        }
       return location;
        
    }

}
```

my unit test

```
public class TestStackTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private TestStack stack;
    
    @Test
    public void paramsTest() {
        Address paramsRequired = Mockito.spy(stack.getAddress(
                "any city", "any", true));
        
        boolean newAddres = paramsRequired==null;
    
        Assert.assertFalse(newAddres);
    }

}
```

I don't think I'm testing anything but honestly, I don't know how to do this test

Comment: Can you please describe what is going on your method, so we can come up with test cases and write tests

Comment: There's no behavior because I haven't done it yet.
I would like to test just this code snippet: `boolean paramsRequired = city!=null || neighborhood!=null;`.
I believe it is very simple because it only analyzes if the two parameters are null, otherwise it goes to the `if` below.